# Markov chain: Is the probability that The machine will break down again (twice in total) Wednesday $b(1-r)$?

Tags: probability, markov-chains, machine-learning, markov-process

chapter 07 of the book "Introduction to Probability, 2nd Edition" gives this example

[image]

> above is the first part, where everything is cool.

[image]

[image]

to understand this, I would like to identify the day with Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday.

The machine is working on Monday.

the probability that The machine will be working Tuesday is $1-b$, whereas the probability that The machine will break down Tuesday is b.

is the probability that The machine will break down again (twice in total) Wednesday $1-r$ or $b(1-r)$? I'll choose the last, and I need a double check.

Comment: Are you asking about the probability of a broken machine on Wednesday given that it was working on Monday or do you want the probability that the machine is broken on Wednesday given that it was working on Monday and broken on Tuesday? Your prior knowledge is very important here and obviously influences the correct answer.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch That is the point which I have been trying to get and didn't get from the book. I just felt something unclear and didn't down which part is unclear, you help me ask the question. Thanks a lot!